# \xRightarrow in \item[...]

Tags: lists, itemize, mathtools, xrightarrow

I would like to put a `\xRightarrow` into a list instead of a bullet, unfortunately I get

```
! Argument of \\xRightarrow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8     \item[$\xRightarrow[continuous]
                                    {norm}$] Test
```

This is from the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\xRightarrow[continuous]{norm}$] Test
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

using

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: as @Phelype Oleinik points out in the comments, this is related to parsing the braces [,].

Comment: Try `\item[{$\xRightarrow[continuous]{norm}$}]`, i.e. add braces around `$\xRightarrow[continuous]{norm}$`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ok thanks, nice and easy solution.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your reply, but I dont see how this is linked to my problem.

Comment: @camelCase The problem is the same (TeX's delimited argument parser), even though the application (optional argument vs. key-value parsing) is a bit different. The delimited macro `\item` looks for a `[` and the first brace-balanced `]`, which (without the braces in Mr. Cat's suggestion) ends up being `$\xRightarrow[continuous`, and then chaos ensues. The braces prevent that. This is explained in my answer to the linked question (see the 5th paragraph there). If after reading that you still disagree on the duplicate, I'll remove my comment, no problem :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik So this actually is a duplicate. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @camelCase You're welcome! Glad it helped :-) Actually, you will find _many_ things related to this, but the two most common (in LaTeX, at least) are optional arguments and comma-separated lists. But that's basically because TeX, Under Usual Circumstances™ doesn't balance `[...]` as it balances `{...}`. There are exceptions, for example commands defined with `xparse`. If you did `\NewDocumentCommand\test{O{z}}{(#1)}` and used `\test[a[b]c]` you'd get `(a[b]c)`, whereas if you used the equivalent `\newcommand\test[1][z]{(#1)}` you'd get `(a[b)c]` for the same input.